# Некорректно отображается кириллица в rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы библиотека svDialogs поддерживала русские буквы.
Ввожу код:

```
library(svDialogs) # Пакет для создания диалоговых окон
data_set = dlg_open(title = "Выберите исходный файл", filters = dlg_filters[c("R", "All"), ])$res
```

Открывается диалоговое окно открытия файла, но в заголовке окна вместо надписи "Выберите исходный файл" пишет черные ромбы со знаками вопроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В RStudio русские буквы тоже заменяет на непонятные символы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding // а лучше воспользуйтесь полноценной операционной системой вместо ms/dos

Comment: Это не ms/dos, а полноценная windows. Приведены скриншоты окна windows  и RStudio.

Comment: Не хотел бы разводить холивар, но что полноценного в Windows, которая за 20 с лишним лет своего развития не смогла или не захотела обеспечить полноценную поддержку юникода?

Comment: Уже начинаю подумывать о переходе на другую операционку.

Comment: Чтобы вам помочь, нужен воспроизводимый пример данных и кода, а также параметры среды, в которой код запускается.